# cannot control youtube video through div

Tags: html, css, youtube

I've embedded a youtube video on my html website and put a transparent div layer over it. I would like the youtube video to play through the div.

My HTML code is this:

```
<iframe  frameborder="0" height="560px" width="315px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DSLgAsrcpGQwmode=opaque"></iframe>
      <div id="overlay"> </div>
```

and the CSS looks like this:

```
#overlay {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  top:0;
  height: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

The problem is I'm not able to click play through the div layer. I don't want the div to disappear when I click. I just want the video to play through the div.

Thanks

Comment: Try using `background-color:transparent` and removing `background` from your CSS.

Comment: Remove the `opacity` as well then. I don't see what the div is doing right now though - its `height` is `0`. Have you removed the div completely to see if the video is able to play through the iframe? Is there anything else on the page?

Comment: [Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jx3rexak/) using your original code - you can click play on the iframe but I don't think it looks quite as you wanted it to.

Comment: The video works without the div. I've put the div because I want to put a transparent image to give the video an effect. the height of the div gets adjusted with the height of the video